# How to make my conditional statement less ugly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, refactoring

I am trying to make the following codes less ugly and not sure what to do. Are there any suggestions from you guys? Thanks 
a lot.

```
  if($element.is('builder') || $element.is('#options') ){
     tooltipYPos=yPos + 35; 
    }

  if($element.is('#button')){
     tooltipXPos=xPos - 240; 
    }
  if($element.is('#addn')){
     tooltipXPos=xPos - 295; 
     tooltipYPos=yPos - 80; 
    }  


   if($element.is('#count')){
     tooltipXPos=xPos + 180; 
     tooltipYPos=yPos - 90; 
    } 
   if($element.is('label')){
       tooltipXPos=xPos + 80; 
     tooltipYPos=yPos - 90; 
   }
```

Comment: Might want to post this over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The general cure is to *move the problem from code to data*. One solution (demonstrated below) is to set up a JavaScript associative array keyed on the various ID tags and the values are value pairs X and Y offsets (in some cases one or the other is 0). At usage time, loop through the keys of the associative array, looking for matches. If so, add the X and Y offsets from the associative array onto toolTipXPos and toolTipYPos.

This will keep your offsets in one place, out of the way, and the code to manipulate them short and simple.

(untested, naturally)

```
// This can be stashed away anywhere.
var a = {
    '#te_classbuilder':              { X: 0,    Y: 35  },
    '#te_options':                   { X: 0,    Y: 35  },
    '#lesson-details-extend-button': { X: -240, Y: 0   },
    '#asset-list-asset-add-button':  { X: 295,  Y: -80 },
    '#asmnt_option_label_q_count':   { X: 180,  Y: -90 },
    "label":                         { X: 80,   Y: -90 }
}

// Put this where you need the actual evaluation to happen  
jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if ( $element.is(key) ) {
        tooltipXPos = xPos + value.X;
        tooltipYPos = yPos + value.Y;
    }
});
```

Edit: changed to loop, so that `label` could be tested for, and not `#label`.

Comment: this code won't work for three reasons. 1) `.id()` is not a valid jQuery function. 2) when you **do** get the id, it won't have a hash in front of it, so you won't get a match in your object `a`. 3) the last case is checking to see if the element is a `<label>` element, not an element with `id="label"`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to make use of jQuery's `.data` function to store the appropriate X and Y values on the elements themselves, like so:

```
$('label').data({ x: 80, y: -90 });
$('#te_classbuilder, #te_options').data({ x: 0, y: 35 });
$('#lesson-details-extend-button').data({ x: -240, y: 0 });
$('#asset-list-asset-add-button').data({ x: -295, y: -80 });
$('#asmnt_option_label_q_count').data({ x: 180, y: -90 });
```

Then, when it comes time to modify your tooltip position values, no conditional statements are required. Simply retrieve the `x` and `y` data attributes from `$element`.

```
tooltipXPos = xPos + $element.data('x');
tooltipYPos = yPos + $element.data('y');
```

This, of course, assumes that any element that may be assigned to `$element` will have previously had `.data` called on it with appropriate `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you work out the height/width of $element and then alter tooltipXPos/tooltipYPos accordingly, instead of hard-coding the deltas?

Answer (score 0):

In first if you can combine conditions:

```
if ($element.is('#te_classbuilder, #te_options')) {
  tooltipYPos = yPos + 35; 
}
```

If we could not make some big changes then I would write it this way:

```
if ($element.is('#te_classbuilder, #te_options')) tooltip = { x: 0,          y: yPos + 35 };
if ($element.is('#lesson-details-extend-button')) tooltip = { x: xPos - 240, y: 0 };
if ($element.is('#asset-list-asset-add-button'))  tooltip = { x: xPos - 295, y: yPos - 80 };
if ($element.is('#asmnt_option_label_q_count'))   tooltip = { x: xPos + 180, y: yPos - 90 };
if ($element.is('label'))                         tooltip = { x: xPos + 80;  y: yPos - 90 };
```